# Spacing in html/css with float

Tags: html, css

I am asking a basic question, but I would like to know how can I add top/bottom spacing to a div container when the float is set to left alignment?
I would like to give lets say 20px space from the top. I have tried adding `top: 20px` but it does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<div>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="download" id="download" class="btn btn-primary" value="GetName" style="float: left">
    <label for="download" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">Download</label>
  </td>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements can't contain `<td>` elements, so it is likely your DOM is completely broken anyway. Start from a basis of valid HTML. https://validator.nu/ can help.

Comment: `float` is great at what it is designed for, but it isn't designed for this. We have flexbox now, so there's no need to use `float` to hack together horizontal layouts.

Comment: Use valid HTML, you can't put a `<td>` inside a `<div>` like you did here. If it is not a table, remove the `<td>` ... Secondly don't use `float` for placing elements, unless you need to support ~15 year old browsers.

Comment: while nothing that was said before is wrong, are you trying to create an email template?

Comment: @tacoshy — Unlikely given they have a checkbox in it.

Comment: Sorry but quite new to this whole html/css. I did not know <td> was not allowed inside a <div>, I had seen a tutorial where <td> was used inside <div><form> </div></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `top: 20px` to work you must set element position to be non-static. E.g. `position: relative;`

```css
.left {
  float: left;
}

.download {
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="download" id="download" class="btn btn-primary left" value="GetName">
      <label for="download" class="left download">Download</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

*I have wrapped your example in table, as your HTML structure is invalid*